# Cannot scrape 'value' from a hidden tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the base price of £6,550 from this link: https://www.plates4less.co.uk/private-plate_o/CSG1S It is in a hidden input called `BasePrice` and when I view the page source '6550' is in an attribute called `value`:

`<input type="hidden" name="BasePrice" id="BasePrice" value="6550">`

My code is:

```
url = 'https://www.plates4less.co.uk/private-plate_o/CSG1S'
req = session.get(url, headers=headers)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(req.text, features="html.parser")
price = bsObj.find("input", {"name" : {"BasePrice"}})
print(price['value'])
```

But it returns `KeyError: 'value'`

When I run this (i.e. retrieving the tag but without trying to access 'value':

```
url = 'https://www.plates4less.co.uk/private-plate_o/CSG1S'
req = session.get(url, headers=headers)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(req.text, features="html.parser")
price = bsObj.find("input", {"name" : {"BasePrice"}})
print(price)
```

I get this:

`<input id="BasePrice" name="BasePrice" type="hidden"/>`

Why am I note able to access the `value` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see on the paga is loaded from external URL. To load the base price, you can use this example:

```py
import json
import requests

# CSG1S is from your base URL
url = "https://www.plates4less.co.uk/apiv3/TransferOptions/CSG1S"

data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment to see all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data["data"]["registrationNumber"]["displayedBPrice"])
```

Prints:

```
6550.0
```

Comment: Thank you! Out of interest, how did you know it was provided by an external URL and find the url it was coming from?

Comment: @Chris I found the URL when I looked to Firefox Developer Tools->Network Tab. There are all URLs the page is connecting.